# How to use yyerror to tell more about parsing errors

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc

So I've written all the grammar I want and everything works smoothly.
I am making absolutely no actions when a grammar is encountered.

This is the definition of my yyerror function

```
int yyerror (const char *s)
{                                                     
    printf("parser error %s \n ",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Well, I've read somewhere that I need to add %error-verbose if I want to get more information about the errors my parser encountered; when I tried to add it I got this error message

> error: unrecognized: %error_verbose

Take into account that I am using Flex, Bison and have connected them with VS2010

**EDIT:** Even though the error mentions error_verbose, I made sure that I am passing error-verbose, with dash instead of an underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly enough, when I tried the %error-verbose on the latest bison version in Linux, it worked just fine but didn't work with the Windows version.

Not sure if it's a bug in the version I am using on Windows or it's just not supported feature.

Comment: Probably just an ancient version of bison you have on Windows.  `bison --version` on the command line should tell you what version it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's `%error-verbose`, with a dash, but your error message shows an underscore instead.

Comment: I did make sure, although I've added it %error-verbose
Bison mentions it encountered %error_verbose...